# How to include metadata with Stripe Checkout client-only implementation?

Tags: stripe-payments, zapier, webflow

I'm using Stripe Checkout's client-only implementation as I have no access to a server (building on Webflow). Implementation is very easy; you just embed some JS. Impressive stuff.

BUT. I'd really like to pass metadata along through the purchase, to be accessible in the purchase info that Zapier uses for a new Strip purchase zap.

The relevant section of the Stripe JS code snippet embedded client-side on my site is this:

```js
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      lineItems: [{price: 'sku_TKTKTKTKT', quantity: 1}],
      mode: 'payment',
      successUrl: 'https://blahblah.com/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://blahblah.com/canceled'
})
```

I've tried adding a `metadata: 'blahblah'` to this JSON; didn't work.

I tried `payment_intent_data.metadata: 'blahblah'` based on [this Stripe doc](https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-metadata-with-checkout-sessions), also to no avail.

Lastly, you can add metadata key-value pairs to the product itself within the Stripe dashboard. Also didn't work.

So does anybody know how to send metadata using Stripe Checkout client-only implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `metadata` on Checkout is only supported with the client-server integration of Checkout and is not supported on client-only Checkout.

Comment: as an alternative approach, do you know if there is a way via Zapier to retrieve a product's metadata, the metadata that is set manually on the product's page in the Stripe admin interface?

Comment: Haven't used Zapier, can you link out to any API docs for their Stripe integration, I can try help

Comment: No problem, but thanks for offering. I can answer my own question by just looking at the output generated by a Stripe charge in Zapier. I just thought you might know something I didn't if you have deep Zapier knowledge. Thanks anyway!